# React collapse pro-sidebar on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a newbie to React. I have a react-pro-sidebar that I want closed/opened on click:

```
export default function MaterialLayout(props) {
 const { children } = props;
 const classes = useStyle();
 function CollapseSide() {
   document.getElementById('pro1').collapsed=!document.getElementById('pro1').collapsed;
 }
 
 return (
   <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
     <CssBaseline /> <Header />
     <ProSidebar id='pro1' onClick={CollapseSide} collapsed={false}>
....
....
```

What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `document.getElementById('pro1').collapsed` you're setting the property on the actual rendered DOM Node and not the React Node.

You can instead try the following

```
export default function MaterialLayout(props) {
 const { children } = props;
 const classes = useStyle();

 const [ sideCollapsed, setSideCollapsed ] = useState(false);
 const toggleSideCollapsed = useCallback(() => {
   console.log('toggle')
   setSideCollapsed(collapsed => !collapsed)
 }, [ setSideCollapsed ]) // could leave this empty
 
 return (
   <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
     <CssBaseline />
     <Header />
     <ProSidebar onClick={toggleSideCollapsed} collapsed={sideCollapsed}>
....
....
```

However I'm not sure whether or not `ProSidebar` takes an `onClick` property. You can verify that using the `console.log` statement and checking your console.

For more explanation you can look into the React docs on `useState` and `useCallback` or just ask in the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try out this code and let me know if it works?

```js
export default function MaterialLayout(props) {
    const { children } = props;
    const classes = useStyle();
    const [toggled, setToggled] = useState(false);
    const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(true);
    const handleToggle = () => {
        setToggled(!toggled);
        setCollapsed(!collapsed);
    }

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline /><Header />
        <ProSidebar collapsed={collapsed} toggled={toggled} onToggle={handleToggle}>
        ...rest of content...
    )
}
```

Comment: No, it does not